# Converting a PHP file into a txt file

Tags: php

I have a php file which takes in data from my SQL database and stores it into a table. I need to create a button which when the user clicks the button it will save that whole page into a .txt file

I have try to use this code

```
<?php $html = file_get_contents('test.php');

  file_put_contents("test.txt","$html");?>
```

But it saves the php code without the data from the database. I assume it does this because it is reading in the file test.php not the web page it creates.

So my question is how can i get it to save the web page it creates with all the data form the SQL database form a button click?

Comment: You need to get the `test.ph` with `file_get_contents("localhost/path/to/your/test.php")`.

Comment: Sorry i had to wait 3 minutes then got tied up with work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Code would be

```
<?php
$test = file_get_contents("http://localhost/test.php");
file_put_contents("test.txt", $test);
```

This code would get the client side html page rather than getting the server side code!

Comment: Note that this will only work if your PHP config allows `file_get_contents()` to fetch a URL. If this config flag is switched off (ie for security reasons) then the above code will not work. In that case, you will need to use CURL or a library like Guzzle to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://localhost/phpinfo.php');
file_put_contents("test.txt",$html);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use curl to run php code and retrieve all the data from the database below is sample

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
// Optional Authentication:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/test.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
file_put_contents("test.txt",$result);

?>
```